# How to manipulate output of a RadioButton in another Button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

i would like to ask what is a way to manipulate the output of a Radio Button in another Button in java?
This is the radiogroup

```
  <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:onClick="Gender"
            android:id="@+id/male"

            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:onClick="Gender"
            android:id="@+id/Female"

            />
```

And this is the Button pressed which should check which radiobutton is checked(male or female)

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="How much should I eat?"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="How_much"


  />
```

Comment: Your question is a bit stuffy but I think using the `isChecked()` and `onCheckChangedListener()` methods (of RadioButtons) will help!

Comment: Please take a moment to read the [questions guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the part regarding [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You show too much code that includes too many irrelevant information. I suggest you yo edit your post and try to be more synthetic.

Comment: Sorry guys its the first time i post here , i will edit it now.

Comment: Edited the context please help me out i only need to understand the concept.